# Proof About P!=NP

Tags: complexity-theory

**Problem description:** 
Given a P-time function(program) pchk:{0,1} ⃰ -> {0,1}. A function f,
f:pchk×ℕ -> {0,1}: f can only simulate pchk with arbitrary argument x.
And, f(pchk,n)==1 iff ∃x, |x|<=n, pchk(x)==1.

Obviously, the time complexity of f is in O(2^N) (the length of pchk can be
assumed a constant). f∈NP and f∉P. Therefore, P!=NP. QED.

There must be something wrong with such a proof, but I cannot figure it out.

**Note:** I read **Naive argument that P ≠ NP** in **Similar questions**. The difference
is that the function f is 'defined' to be in O(2^n).

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: Also note that $\mathsf{P}$ and $\mathsf{NP}$ are sets of languages (or problems), not sets of functions (or algorithms).

Comment: I don't get what you mean. f is a decision function. f can be implemented by NDTM.

Comment: You probably meant to use $\Omega(\cdot)$ instead of $O(\cdot)$. "f can only simulate pchk with arbitrary argument x" requires a proof, how do you know that there is no algorithm that decides whether $pchk(x)=1$ for some $x$ by looking at the description of $pchk$? "The length of pchk can be
assumed a constant" why? If the length is at most a constant then there are only finitely many functions $pchk$ and one can compute $f$ in constant time by hardcoding the answers. "Obviously, the time complexity of [computing?] $f$ is in $\Omega(2^N)$ [I replaced $O(\cdot)$]" This requires a proof.

Comment: 1."f can only simulate pchk with arbitrary argument x", this is the problem 
definition. 2.pchk can be a given TM description to compute x (so f can 
'simulate' it). pchk is a constant length input to f, but f has no way to
hard-coding it. However, the problem definition already says "f can only simulate pchk with arbitrary argument x".

Comment: If you want to show $P \neq NP$ with this strategy you need to exhibit a problem in $NP$ such that **no algorithm** that runs in time $O(poly(n))$, where $n$ is the input size, can solve it. You cannot arbitrarily add restrictions to what the algorithm is allowed to do. Also, if you assume contradictory things ($f$ works for infinitely many inputs, but somehow the size of the input is constant?) then you can derive anything. Finally, in the question and in the comments you misuse $O(\cdot)$. If an algorithm for a problem $A$ takes $O(f(n))$ time, $A$ could still admit faster algorithms.

Comment: For "now" we can/have to assume: `P != NP`. For "infinity"/"day x", we "will see"/can assume: `P == NP`.  (what difference might there be between "polynomial" and "non-polynomial" in "eternity"? ...no significant! ;) ...ergo: "now" is not "eternity"! 

Answer (score 1):

You didn't prove any lower bound here, which is required to imply that $P\neq NP$, but rather you have shown an upper bound.

So essentially you have shown that the problem is in $Exp$ but you haven't proven that the problem is *not* in $P$

Comment: I think the answer misses the main point: namely, that $f \in NP$ is a category error.

Comment: I absolutely agree with that, but even when glossing over that detail, in the higher level of the question - the OP tried to prove $P\neq NP$ by showing that there is an exponential algorithm to some problem - which definitely won't prove it (no matter what algorithm / problem it is for)

Comment: The problem is like guessing password, f must count x. f has to be in O(2^n), you might say f 'is defined' to be an O(2^n) function and in NP as well.

Comment: @wij you will have to prove that you *can't* have a better algorithm for your argument to be correct. Showing that an algorithm exists does not suffice for this, and an argument like "its like guessing a password so it can't be done better" is not a proof either. Also, you will have to explicitly show that the problem is in $NP$, since having an $O(2^n)$ deterministic algorithm does not imply a polynomial non-deterministic one.

Comment: @nirshahar, `no matter what algorithm / problem it is for`: I believe that the issue is that OP doesn't seem to understand all the things you mentioned: the algorithm $A$ is solving some problem $X$ (and being/not being in NP is the property of $X$, not of $A$). I.e. they completely miss the whole layer of understanding: namely, that such $X$ exists, and we must talk about $X$ (and question if a better algorithm for $X$ exists). And so they continue talking about $A$: `f 'is defined' to be an O(2^n) function`.

Comment: Thanks, nir shahar. I though the mentioned two points are obvious. Proving cracking password by brute force is O(2^n) might not be terse. However, My intention was asking question, not trying to prove